# How does the F-16 achieve negative stability?

Tags: fighter, stability

[F-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Dynamics_F-16_Fighting_Falcon) has negative stability at subsonic conditions. How is this achieved? To me it looks like a very streamligned, very normally shaped aircraft.

Is the Center of Mass actually behind the Center of Lift? If so, how? I looked up dry engine weight as a fraction of total empty weight, and got 16%. For dry engine weight as a fraction of normal loaded weight, I got 12%.

All the weapons and ammo seem to be ahead of the body or in the middle of the wings or body. So the only thing left is fuel but I cannot imagine how you could fit a large amount of fuel very far aft in that small jet.

Is there some other way it achieves negative stability? How does the F-16 do it?

Comment: You cannot tell where CG is from just looking at it. Engine is in  the back. It weighs a bit.

Comment: The wings are shifted forward relative to a stable design. A few inches are enough already.

Comment: @PeterKämpf It sort of does, but it depends on the terminology "negative stability" and "relaxed stability". I see those two terms used interchangeably but ive always thought the first has C_g behind C_L, whereas the latter means C_g and C_L coincide (or extremely close). Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Nothing to correct. The difference is indeed how much the cg has been moved back. But the principle is the same and the difference in cg location is small.